# What is the proper way to use flex to fill remaining horizontal space within a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have built a html tab menu.

```
<section id="container">

<div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
<div class="tab>Tab 2</div>
<div class="tab>Tab 3</div>
<div class="tab>Tab 4</div>
<div id="rest_of_space_v2></div>

</section>
```

I am trying to use flex to make `<div id="rest_of_space_v2></div>` fill the remainder of the container.

```
#container{}
.tab{float: left; padding: 5px;}
#rest_of_space_v2 {float: left; display: flex;  flex-direction: row; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

I have tried multiple things but I am not understanding the child element of it. The flex element is essentially just a `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;` to continue the border on the tabs.

I am sure it is simple enough but wondered if anyone had any advice.

Comment: The real problem is that I don't understand it. I have watched videos and cannot wrap my head around it. It doesn't fill the remainder of the container. Just a percentage of it.

Comment: is it possible to talk in chat?

Comment: you are trying to mix 2 methods `float: left; display: flex;` when `float`is nowdays no longer needed for layout  ;) . flex or grid are so efficient and easy that float should be used for its original purpose not layouts. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from `#rest_of_space_v2`.